# How to find node with highest count?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Using XPath or a XQuery, how do I select the node with the most occurrences of another node?

For example how do I find the basket which has the most eggs?

```
<basket name="1">
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
</basket>
<basket name="2">
        <egg></egg>
</basket>
<basket name="3">
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
</basket>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one solution (TIMTOWTDI):

```
let $nodes := <xml>
  <basket name="1">
          <egg></egg>
          <egg></egg>
  </basket>
  <basket name="2">
          <egg></egg>
  </basket>
  <basket name="3">
          <egg></egg>
          <egg></egg>
          <egg></egg>
          <egg></egg>
  </basket>
</xml>
let $max := max(for $c in $nodes//basket return count($c/egg))
return $nodes/basket[count(egg) = $max]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! 
The sample code I posted was less complex than the problem I needed to solve. This solution was the one I could most easily adapt. Thank you also to @dimitri and Roman

Answer (score 1):

**This is both an XPath 2.0 expression and an XQuery, that selects the wanted element(s)**:

```
/*/basket[egg[max(/*/basket/count(egg))]]
```

**XSLT 2.0  - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="/*/basket[egg[max(/*/basket/count(egg))]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (your provided XML fragment, wrapped into a single top element to become a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <basket name="1">
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
    </basket>
    <basket name="2">
        <egg></egg>
    </basket>
    <basket name="3">
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
    </basket>
</t>
```

**The XPath expression is evaluated and the result of the evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
<basket name="3">
        <egg/>
        <egg/>
        <egg/>
        <egg/>
    </basket>
```

**Do note**:

There is no such thing as "**the node** with the most occurances of another node".

In fact, depending on the actual XML document, there may be many elements that contain the same maximum number of other elements.

**If you want to obtain just one such element, say the first in document order, then use**:

```
/*/basket[egg[max(/*/basket/count(egg))]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xml>
    <basket name="1">
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
    </basket>
    <basket name="2">
        <egg></egg>
    </basket>
    <basket name="3">
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
        <egg></egg>
    </basket>
</xml>
```

you can try XPath like that

```
xml/basket[
    count(egg) > count(following-sibling::*/egg) and
    count(egg) > count(preceding-sibling::*/egg)
]
```

or if you want to count not only egg elements

```
xml/basket[
    count(child::*) > count(following-sibling::*/child::*) and
    count(child::*) > count(preceding-sibling::*/child::*)
]
```